# Ajax request fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm doing a contact form and I'm trying to use AJAX. I've followed some youtube guide, but the code didn't work for me. I believe the problem is with the `datosEnviados` object, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried using parse function but it didn't work either.

The error I get is the following
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (...)`

The code of my JS function is:

```js
function ejecutarAjax(event) {

    var datosEnviados = {
        "nombre":$('#nombres').val(),
        "email":$('#email').val(),
        "comentario":$('#comentario').val()
        }


    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : '../php/enviar_contacto.php',
        data    : datosEnviados,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode  : true
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert("ok");
    })
    .fail(function(jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax when defining `datosEnviados` or is it something else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like the problem is in json output, so you better check/debug your `enviar_contacto.php`

Comment: Try: `dataType: 'html'`, and if no errors in this case, then check your json output.

Comment: Your are using json dataType. should use json_decode function in enviar_contacto.php page, or alternative follow @NoSkill comment

Comment: In your reply from JavaScript you are receiving HTML, and you are asking for JSON explicitly. And because you are not receiving valid JSON, you get the error that the very fist character of the "EXPECTED JSON" is an invalid character "<". To fix it. in `enviar_contacto.php` the end output should be `json_encode($the_output_string);`

Comment: @NoSkill I changed to html and it is working! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
function ejecutarAjax(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //This should be at top

var datosEnviados = {
    //Try with replace "nombre" to nombre(Remove "")
     number : $('#nombres').val(),
     email : $('#email').val(),
     comentario : $('#comentario').val()
    }
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : '../php/enviar_contacto.php',
        data    : datosEnviados,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode  : true
    })
```

**Alternative**

```
function ejecutarAjax(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //This should be at top

    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : '../php/enviar_contacto.php',
        data    : {
               nombre : $('#nombres').val(),
               email : $('#email').val(),
               comentario : $('#comentario').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
             //Your code goes here
        }
    })
```

Hopefully, this will work

Comment: Also he can use newForm()